# Ignoring spces in substr()

Tags: php, substr

I am using a substr() to get the last digits from a number. However, it takes spaces into consideration too. Is there a way to avoid it? Using preg_replace to remove spaces first is not an option, since I want them (spaces) in the outcome.

`substr($match[0], -5)`

To give you an example how it looks now:

123456789 - the numbers 56789 will show

1234 56 78 9 - depending where the spaces are it may show nothing or 78 or 7 or 9, etc.

Comment: What outcome do you want if the string is "1234 56 78 9"?

Comment: What about `preg_replace` (or even `str_replace` since a regex isn't needed for a space character) and assign the result to a new variable?

Comment: Not a regex expert - but would `(\d[ ]*){5,5}$` do it?

Comment: is it a number or a string ?

Comment: if it is number you can apply modulus  operator % to get last digit

Comment: @somega I want it to be `56 78 9` (i want the spaces to be ignored and the last 5 numbers to show.

Comment: @user3783243 Will the string_replace remove the spaces completely? I am not sure how to do that without removing spaces in the outcome. Can you give an examples?

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? e.g. what `$match[0]` or `$match` contains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can remove the spaces before calling substr

```
substr(str_replace(" ", "", $match[0]), -5)
```

Or, if you want preserve spaces

```
function RightSubstrIgnoreChar($string, $length, $IgnoreChar = ' ') {
    $r = "";
    for ($n = strlen($string) - 1; $n >= 0 && strlen(str_replace($IgnoreChar, "", $r)) < $length; $n--) {
        $r = substr($string, $n, 1) . $r;
    }
    return $r;
}

echo RightSubstrIgnoreChar("1234 56 78 9", 5);
```

Output

```
56 78 9
```